# Offline maps support for iOS 6. Is that possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I am developing app that has map functionality and i want to support offline maps as well. Is that possible? Also is it possible to show route with openInMapsWithLaunchOptions without network?

Comment: nope, not unless you make one which runs all the routing algorithms on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with any level of predictability or control with MapKit, but you can with both [MBXMapKit](http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit) and the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk). Both have robust offline support built in.